# Python- Extracting archives, and manipulating them

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python, and SO. I've been searching for an answer to my question, and have found some promising, relevant material, but none that really address my exact question:

I'm writing a script in Python 3 that will download an archive file (.tgz) from a website, extract it, and run it. The archive contains two directories that I'd like to manipulate- /bin and /lib. The problem is that once I extract the archive, the directories I want are placed within a Parent directory who's name can vary depending on the date and version- So, for example, when I extract it, it goes from `Download.tgz`-> `/Download2019.02.113` which contains the two desired folders.

I want to get to the /bin and /lib folders, but the parent directory, with its potentially changing name, means I can't just hard-code a command to move into `/Download2019.02.113` and expect it to work if they keep releasing new versions in the future. Is there a good way to bypass this issue, so I can continue to work with the directories within?

Sorry if this is an overly wordy explanation, with no actual code to analyze. It's more of a theory question rather than "Why isn't this code working?". Thank you to anyone who can give any input at all.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (i.e. code + directory structure).

Comment: The [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module should provide the heavy lifting. The `os` module would help you create directories, rename things, etc.